# How are __repr__ and __str__ implemented in print function

Tags: python-3.x

The way that I understand about `__str__` and `__repr__` through googling is that `__str__`is called when `print`or `__str__()` function is used and the output is always string. `__repr__` is called when `repr()` or `__repr__()` function is used and while `repr()` can only output string, `__repr__()` could be any valid python expression such as tuple, dictionary, string etc.

So I was creating a two class Person and CircularQueue. In person class, it contains variable **name**, **age** and I defined `__str__` and `__repr__`. For CircularQueue class, it is ordinal CQ except it only accepts Person class.

For `print(cg.dequeue())` it prints only the **name** as I expected with `__str__`. However, when I run `print(cg.multi_dequeue(3))`, it gives the output of `__repr__` and not `__str__`. I thought that since I used `print` it would use `__str__`.

1. Why `print(cg.dequeue())` output using `__str__` while `print(cg.multi_dequeue(3))` output using `__repr__`?
2. This question is not really connected to the topic but why can't I use `return self` in `__repr__` even if I use `cg.multi_dequeue(3).__repr__()`? It gives `TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type Person)` error.

```
class Person:
        name = ""
        age = 0

        def __init__(self, name, age):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
        def __repr__(self):
            return ("[Person(name: " + self.name + ", age: " + str(self.age) + ")")
            #return self
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class CircularQueue:
...
    def enqueue(self, element):
        check = isinstance(element,Person)
        #check if CQ is full
        if self.is_full():
            print("Queue is full!")
            return 0
        #check if input is Person class
        elif check != True:
            print("Element is not a Person class element")
            return 0
        #add element to CQ
        else:
            self.queue[self.rear] = element
            self.rear = (self.rear + 1) % self.M
    def dequeue(self):
        #check if CQ is empty
        if self.is_empty():
            print("Queue is empty")
            return 0
        #return element
        else:
            temp = self.queue[self.front]
            self.queue[self.front] = None
            self.front = (self.front +1) % self.M
            return temp
    def multi_dequeue(self, count):
        temp = []
        for i in  range(count):
            temp.append(self.dequeue())
        return temp

def main():
    cg = CircularQueue(10)
    cg.enqueue(Person("hi",1))
    cg.enqueue(Person("bye",1))
    cg.enqueue(Person("dd",3))
    cg.enqueue(Person("ss",3))
    cg.enqueue(Person("aa",3))
    print(cg.dequeue())
    print(cg.multi_dequeue(3))

main()
```

output

```
hi
[[Person(name: bye, age: 1), [Person(name: dd, age: 3), [Person(name: ss, age: 3)]
```

Comment: You can almost answer the question yourself. The output depends on the depth of the object and the implementation of the object or type. It is a kind of class recursion in a tree.

Comment: @Detlef I'm sorry I'm new to python and I don't quite get your comment. May you please elaborate more? Isn't the depth all the same since they are all in a CircularQueue class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is not very good. I will try another one.

The difference between `__repr__` and `__str__` lies in the information value. The standard implementation is `__repr__` and returns the class and the hash of the instance, which represents the memory address, as this is used by the interpreter for unique identification. It is the unique representation of an object's instance. However, this is not always helpful for the user. This is where `__str__` comes into play.

Inheritance is an illustration of a tree structure. Every time you inherit from a class or type, you add another child node to the tree. The deeper you are in the tree, the more information may be available about the individual nodes.
Within my implementation of a tree you can see that the unique identification is given by the class, the module path and the content. However, the actual content of the node is more interesting for the user. However, this can vary depending on the use or depth within the tree.

Due to the amount of data that is collected in a sequence / iterable, it makes more sense to continuously output the `__repr__` variant. In my implementation the `__str__` output would make no sense, would change constantly and go beyond the scope if I wanted to output the entire tree. So with `__str__` I only return the string of the real data. Remember, there may be a node that appears at a different location in the tree but contains the same content. These appear the same but are different.

Unfortunately I can't give you a better explanation. I hope it's not too weird and complicated.
Think about it.
I believe in you!

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import List

class BaseNode(ABC):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._children = []
        self._parent = None

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._children)

    def __repr__(self):
        # python default implementation of __repr__
        return f'<{self.__class__.__module__}.{self.__class__.__name__}' \
            f' object at {self.__hash__()}>'

    # python default implementation of __str__
    __str__ = __repr__

    def has_children(self) -> bool:
        return len(self) > 0

    def is_leaf(self) -> bool:
        return not self.has_children()

    def is_root(self) -> bool:
        return self._parent is None

    def add(self, child: 'BaseNode') -> 'BaseNode':
        self._children.append(child)
        child._parent = self
        return self

    def depth(self) -> int:
        d,n = 0,self
        while not n.is_root():
            d,n = d+1,n._parent
        return d

    def descendants(self) -> List['Node']:
        arr = []
        if self.is_leaf(): return arr
        else:
            arr.extend(self._children)
            for child in self._children:
                arr.extend(child.descendants())
        return arr

    # abstract
    def remove(self, child: 'BaseNode') -> 'BaseNode':
        self._children.remove(child)
        child._parent = None
        return self


class RootNode(BaseNode):
    pass

class Node(BaseNode):
    def __init__(self, content):
        super().__init__()
        self._content = content

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    @property
    def content(self):
        return self._content


def main():
    node = RootNode()
    node_a   = Node('Node 1')
    node_aa  = Node('Node 1.1')
    node_ab  = Node('Node 1.2')
    node_aba = Node('Node 1.2.1')
    node_b   = Node('Node 2')
    node_ba  = Node('Node 2.1')

    node_ab.add(node_aba)
    node_a.add(node_aa)
    node_a.add(node_ab)
    node.add(node_a)
    node_b.add(node_ba)
    node.add(node_b)

    print(node)
    print(str(node))
    print(repr(node))
    print(node.depth())
    print(node.descendants())

    print(node_aba)
    print(str(node_aba))
    print(repr(node_aba))
    print(node_aba.depth())
    print(node_aba.descendants())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
``
```